# How We create a textfield behave as autocomplete by onkeypress event in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, autocomplete, textfield

How We create a textfield behave as autocomplete by onkeypress evnet in java as Database is Mysql.

Comment: -1 for absolutely no effort shown!

Comment: Look up SwingLabs, they have a auto complete decorate for text fields and comboboxes

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `DocumentFilter` (thanks MadProgrammer) instead of a `KeyListener`. The former is more reliable and easier to deal with.

Also instead of a `JTextField` you should use a `JComboBox` instead to show a drop down after the user begins typing.

Now I will not put the effort into creating some code for you since you did not show effort in asking the question.

Read up on:

- [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)
- [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Comment: I would not.  I would suggest a `DocumentFilter` instead over a `DocumentListener`.  If you try and modify a text field from within a `DocumentListener` you are likely to cause a exception of some sort (sorry can't remember the type).  `DocumentFilter` will allow you to intercept the change before it's applied to the document and modify what is been added/removed

Comment: True, `DocumentFilter` is probably better in this situation.